# Calculate the new top offset of the new added div after closing old divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollview, offset

[image]

Users can add blocks in such form so I need to scroll the new added block into view and it's working correctly BUT I tried to close old blocks like opened (Block 2, Block 3) then scroll to (Block 4) top offset but it's not working.

After adding the new block i'll close the old opened blocks and scroll to the new one.

So I need to calculate the new top offset of the new div (Block 4) AFTER closing old divs (Block 2, Block 3) then scroll to the new offset.

The following code works only if the old blocks retained its old state.

```
var curBlockOffsetTop = $(#divID).offset().top;

$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: curBlockOffsetTop - 40
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

How are the old blocks being closed? There's not enough detail in your question.

It sounds like what's happening is that curBlockOffsetTop is reading the height before the blocks are closed, then when the scroll animation fires it scrolls to the wrong place. Try using a setTimeout to delay execution of the scroll until everything is closed if this is the case.

It would look like this:

```
/**closing old blocks code goes here**/

var delayInMiliseconds = 1200;

setTimeout(function(){

/**scrolling code goes here**/

}, delayInMiliseconds);
```

Comment: I modified the question, Thanks

Comment: I still think this is happening because the events are not executing in the order that you want them to. Did you try using a setTimeout like I suggested?

Answer (score 0):

How about instead of scrolling to the new block, you scroll to the end of the last block?

I am not sure how your markup is, but let's say it's something like this:

```
<div class="block-1"></div>
<div class="block-2"></div>
<div class="block-3"></div>
<div class="block-4">
   New Block that was just added
</div>

<script>
   newPosish = $(".block-3").offset().top $(".block-3").height() + 40 // where block-4 should be added
   window.scrollTo(0,newPosish)
</script>
```

Comment: these are dynamic blocks and each block has its own height

Comment: answer edited.. correct, the height needs to be added as well

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but if the (Block 2) was opened (like figure) the top offset of the (Block 3) will be taken before collapsing the two blocks (Block 2, Block 3) so it's the same issue, It calculates the old offset not the new one after collapsing